# Website scraping with Python, how do I know where to reference in the html?

Tags: python, html, class, beautifulsoup

I'm a complete beginner who has only built basic Python projects. Right now I'm building a scraper in Python with bs4 to help me read success stories off of a website. These success stories are all in a table, so I thought I would find an html tag that said table and would encompass the entire table.

However, it is all just <div and <span class, and when I use soup.find("div") or ("span") it returns only the single word "div" or "span". This is what I have so far, and I know it isn't right or set up correctly but I'm too inexperienced to know why yet.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests
req = Request('https://www.calix.com/about-calix/success-stories.html', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
soup.find("div", {"id": "content-calix-en-site-prod-home-about-calix-success-stories-jcr-content"})
print('div')
```

I have watched several tutorials on how to use bs4 and I have successfully scraped basic websites, but all I can do for this one is get ALL of the html, not the chunks I need (just the success stories).

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `'div'` make sure to be printing soup as soup gets updated whenever you find something within it.

You should have a look at the [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find("div", {"id": "content-calix-en-site-prod-home-about-calix-success-stories-jcr-content"})
```

Here you're calling `soup.find()` but you're not saving the results into a variable, so the results are lost.

```
print('div')
```

And here you're printing the literal string `div`.  I don't think that's what you intended.

Try something like this:

```
div = soup.find("div", {"id": "..."})
print(div)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help! I tried that but it returned with "None" this time. Is there a disconnect between what I just scraped and my new request? It's like it is not reading the html at all.